# Create GitHub issue for current repository

Tags: github

I'd like to be able to create GitHub issues from Emacs using a simple command, e.g.

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `create-github-issue` <kbd>RET</kbd> `<title>` <kbd>RET</kbd> `<comment>` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Ideally, the command would default to the current repo when called from a buffer visiting a file that belongs to a `git` repository.

I checked the repos ([ELPA](https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/), [MELPA](http://melpa.org/#/), [Marmalade](http://marmalade.ferrier.me.uk/)); the closest thing I could find is [`gh`](https://github.com/sigma/gh.el), which is a

> GitHub API library for Emacs.

It includes [`gh-issues.el`](https://github.com/sigma/gh.el/blob/master/gh-issues.el) which looks like it could be used as a starting point for implementing such a feature. *But since I don't want to reinvent the wheel:*

Does anybody have a hand-rolled solution for this that they could share (or know of a package that I missed that implements this functionality)?

Comment: [emacs-bts-github](https://github.com/aki2o/emacs-bts-github) has a `bts-github::add-issue` function, I think it already has what you want, but I have not used this package.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using syohex's [emacs-helm-open-github](https://github.com/syohex/emacs-helm-open-github) which provides a set of commands to open issues/files/commits's URL in Github easily, it uses the gh library as well, I look down its code and change its `helm-open-github--collect-issues` function into `create-github-issue`:

```
(defun create-github-issue (title body)
  (let ((remote-url (helm-open-github--remote-url)))
    (cl-multiple-value-bind (user repo) (helm-open-github--extract-user-host remote-url)
      (gh-issues-issue-new helm-open-github-issues-api
                           user repo
                           (gh-issues-issue :title title
                                            :body body)))))
```

`helm-open-github--extract-user-host` is used for getting user/repo, `gh-issues-issue-new` is used for creating new issue.

To use it, try `(create-github-issue "issue title" "issue content")`, a example result: https://github.com/xuchunyang/emacs.d/issues/2

Comment: @Sibi It's easy to do, I mean, read issue title & body from minibuffer, but I don't think it's a good idea.

Comment: Thanks, Why it isn't a good idea ?

Comment: Because minibuffer is usually for reading a small amount text like Emacs command name, file name, while issue's body usually consists of several complete sentences. An interface like `M-x mail RET` is much better for this    use case.

Comment: Thanks, this seems like a good starting point for implementing what I am looking for. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. When I evaluate `(create-github-issue "issue title" "issue content")` from a file that belongs to a `git` repo I get: `Debugger entered--Lisp error: (invalid-slot-name "#<gh-issues-issue :title>" "issue title") [...]`.

Comment: It works fine from here. I am unfamiliar with the gh library nor the eieio library, but I guess `(gh-issues-issue :title "title" :body "body")` will fail as well, so it could be a bug of the gh library.